# How to select JSON value as int in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql

I've a value of `jsonb` which has a key that contains an `int`.

I'd like to insert this into a table with an `int` column. I get an error of `ERROR:  column "abr" is of type integer but expression is of type text
LINE 4:   values->>'abr' as abr,`

```
select
  values->>'_filename' as _filename,
  values->>'abr' as abr
from   temp_json;
```

How can I select the value with a key of `abr` as an int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
select
  values->>'_filename' as _filename,
  (values->>'abr')::int as abr
from   temp_json;
```